# can't access mongo db values

Tags: mongodb, express, passport.js

hello there first of all let me tell I am new to node js, I am trying to make a login form using mongodb and passport.I have got two modules in it server.js and auth.js,my problem is that I want to access the values from my mongo server and check if the user name and password is correct can someone please help me out

auth.js

```
var passport = require('passport'),
    LocalStrategy = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/user'); 
var user = mongoose.model('val', Schema);   
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
    user.find({},function(username,password,done){
        if(username === firstName && password === password12) {
            return done(null,{username: 'admin'});
        }
        else{

        }
        return done(null,false);
    })
));
passport.serializeUser(function(user,done) {
    done(null,user.firstName);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function(username,done) {
    done(null,{username: firstName});
});
module.exports = passport;
```

server.js

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var functions = require('functions'); 
var path = require('path');
var passport = require('./auth.js');
var flash = require('connect-flash');
var mongodb = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var app = express();
var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
app.use(flash());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: false
}));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/user');
var Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstName: String,
    lastName: String,
    email: String,
    password12: String,
})

var user = mongoose.model('val', Schema);

app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.render('signup', {
        firstName: "factWeavers"
    });
});
app.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
    new user({
        firstName: req.body.username,
        lastName: req.body.lastName,
        email: req.body.email,
        password12: req.body.password12,
    }).save(function (err, doc) {
        if (err) res.json(err);
        else console.log("information passed successfully");
        res.redirect('/login');
    });
});



app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.render('login');
});
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect: '/signup',
    successRedirect: '/access'
}));
functions.login = function(req, res) {
    res.render('login',{title:hey})
}
app.get('/access', function (req, res) {
    res.render('access');
});
functions.access = function(req, res) {
    if (req.session.passport.user === undefined) {
        res.redirect('/login');
    } else {
        res.render('user')
    }
};

var server = app.listen('8090', function () {
    console.log("Server running at localhost:8090");
});
```

this is what i have done and thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
 function(username, password, done) {
    User.findOne({ firstName: username }, function (err, user) { // find the user with firstName as given username from mongoDB
      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { // if no user is found with the provided firstName
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username.' });
      }
      if (!(user.password==password)) { // Check if the password is wrong
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password.' });
      }
      return done(null, user); // Login success
    });
  }
```